# PostGIS: Importing GEOM polygons data from hundreds of different tables into one?

Tags: import, postgis

Fairly new to PostGIS, would appreciate any insight....

I'm importing hundreds of Shapefiles into my database in an effort to find all polygon records that contain a coordinate using ST_Within(). I know it's possible to do a select statement that includes all tables in the schema, but I've had limited success.

I'm tempted to import all the various tables into a single Master table, but figure I might be making more work for myself and I'd risk having the PostGIS community laugh at me. ;)

If any one has a smarter way to go about this, I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: hey there, have you considered a materialised view or even using table partitioning?

Comment: @jimjones, I haven't. But, I'll look it up. Thank you for your insight!